# Programmatically call default media player in Blackberry?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

Like I said, the application has to call the default Blackberry media player.Does anybody know or maybe point in a direction to implement it

Enviroment : Eclipse+BB plugin 4.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

The first approach would be to use the content handler mechanisms of the device. You'll essentially be forcing the device to deal with a given file in a default manner. For audio files, the default manner would be to launch the media player on the device with the file.

So, for example if you have a file called song.mp3 on the SD card on the device, you would do something like the following (code is from memory, haven't checked it in a while):

```
Invocation invocation = new Invocation("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/music/song.mp3"); 
Registry reg = Registry.getRegistry("net.rim.device.api.content.BlackBerryContentHandler");
reg.invoke(invocation);
```

The second approach would be to use the content handler in the BlackBerry web browser to, essentially, accomplish the same thing. In the case of a browser, you can use the standard classes related to **net.rim.blackberry.api.browser.BrowserSession** to launch an instance of a browser with the URL to the music file. The URL can be something on the web, or, as above, it can be a file:// location on the device itself. This will cause the browser to deal with the content, which will essentially launch the music player and play the file.